# of which vs. whose

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

Would anyone please tell me simply when/ in which situation the followings are the same and interchangeable? and when they are not?

> *- of which* 
>  *- whose*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use "of which" to precede the object of possession.
So they're not interchangeable synctactically. Also to ask about possesion you must use whose, see Maulik V answer.

> It was a war the effect **of which** still continues.
>   It was a war **whose** effect still continues.

Comment: What is wrong with _the war **of which** the effect_ still continues? The reason your "wrong" sentence is wrong is because you left out the article, if you leave out the article in your first sentence, it is as wrong. That has nothing to do with the position of _of which_.

Comment: I've never heard something like "of which the effect" so it sounded so strange to me, but after searching, I'm certainly wrong. Editing...

Answer (score 0):

In the following sentences, they are **the same** (first concern of yours)

*'Of which' serves as a relative clause.* And, *a comma* would make sentence clear. In below mentioned sentence, since the phrase serves as 'relative clause', I'll be needing an article to introduce *door.*

> It's the house whose door is painted red = It's the house, of which *a/the* door is painted red.

In the following sentences, they are **not the same** (second concern of yours)

> Whose house is that? **cannot be written like this** Of which house is that?

[Further reading is here.](http://www.grammarbank.com/whose-of-which-of-whom.html)